# Steamer with single vent instead of bottom holes

Tags: equipment, steaming

My family has owned a stainless steel steamer for a long time with a single raised vent to let steam into the upper compartment. It's great because there's no way for food to get into the bottom compartment so it (mostly) never has to be washed. It only ever contains water.

[image: picture of steamer]

I really want to buy one of these but the only steamers I can find for sale have a perforated bottom in the upper compartment. Does anyone know where I can buy one or if any company still manufactures these?

Answer (score 3):

I have a stainless steel steamer/juicer similar to the one picture w/o perforation. It has a tube that dispels the juice into any container you choose right from the middle pan as it extracts.  I purchased mine from Amazon and it is a product of Cook N Home.